# Viewport Issues/ no scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having issues with a site, I've read the overflow-y: can be the issue, but it doesn't appear to be. Some of the site appears to get cut off when viewing in a smaller mode, and it does not allow scrolling. Could this happen with bootstrap's css? I used a full screen image as the background and maybe its forcing every viewport to view the full image

[website](http://www.4tier.it/smc/)

I can post the CSS, but its the same as the link above. Any help is truly appreciated. At my wits end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this with three changes. First, you need to change your css for `#home` as follows:

```
#home {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This will turn scrolling on for the main area but not for the header menu. Maybe that is what you want, but if not - the second thing I changed was I moved the `menu-wrap` element into the `home` element. You should (roughly) end up with something like:

```
<article id="home" class="active">
    <div id="menu-wrap"><!--html here --></div>
    <div class="proppage"><!--html here --></div>
    <!-- etc -->
</article>
```

That will get you closer to having the menu scroll with the page but to finally make it scroll you can't set the position to `fixed`. What you are actually looking for here is `absolute`. Note that fixed keeps it at that location in the browser where absolute keeps it at that location on the page. Your updated css with this change looks like:

```
#menu-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

This is pretty close to what you are probably looking for. Hope that helps!

Comment: Drew_w you've helped tremendously. Your answer has fixed the issue!

Comment: @SirSwish Feel free to mark as the answer if it helps : )

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery slimscroll. I had the same problem.

```
<div class="slim-scroll" data-height="auto" data-disable-fade-out="true">
     -----Code to scroll----
</div>
```